# @RequestBody @Valid SomeDTO has field of enum type, custom error message

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

I have the following `@RestController`

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity(@RequestBody @Valid SomeDTO, BindingResult errors) {
//do something with errors if validation error occur
}

public class SomeDTO {
   public SomeEnum someEnum;
}
```

If the JSON request is `{ "someEnum": "valid value" }`, everything works fine. However, if the request is `{ "someEnum": "invalid value" }`, it only return error code 400.

How can I trap this error so I can provide a custom error message, such as "someEnum must be of value A/B/C".

Comment: Please check https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api.html, it shows how to use @ControllerAdvice

Comment: @AmitKBist this doesn't answer the question on enum type

Answer (score 10):

The answer provided by @Amit is good and works. You can go ahead with that if you want to deserialize an enum in a specific way. But that solution is not scalable. Because every enum which needs validation must be annotated with `@JsonCreator`.

Other answers won't help you beautify the error message.

So here's my solution generic to all the enums in spring web environment.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    public static final String BAD_REQUEST = "BAD_REQUEST";
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException exception,
                                                               HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String genericMessage = "Unacceptable JSON " + exception.getMessage();
        String errorDetails = genericMessage;

        if (exception.getCause() instanceof InvalidFormatException) {
            InvalidFormatException ifx = (InvalidFormatException) exception.getCause();
            if (ifx.getTargetType()!=null && ifx.getTargetType().isEnum()) {
                errorDetails = String.format("Invalid enum value: '%s' for the field: '%s'. The value must be one of: %s.",
                        ifx.getValue(), ifx.getPath().get(ifx.getPath().size()-1).getFieldName(), Arrays.toString(ifx.getTargetType().getEnumConstants()));
            }
        }
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
        errorResponse.setTitle(BAD_REQUEST);
        errorResponse.setDetail(errorDetails);
        return handleExceptionInternal(exception, errorResponse, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

}
```

This will handle all the invalid enum values of all types and provides a better error message for the end user.

Sample output:

```
{
    "title": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "detail": "Invalid enum value: 'INTERNET_BANKING' for the field: 'paymentType'. The value must be one of: [DEBIT, CREDIT]."
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public static class GenericExceptionHandlers extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException e, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorDTO().setError(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

I created a fully functional Spring boot Application with a Test on  [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/Klaus_Groenbaek/so/overview)

Comment: Can we make it more specific to Enums? `HttpMessageNotReadableException` is a very broad exception and will cover a lot of other exceptions like invalid json

Answer (score 4):

You do not need @Valid for enum validation, you can achieve the required response using below code:

Controller Code, StackDTO has an enum PaymentType in it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reviews", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestBody StackDTO review) {

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

Create an exception class, as EnumValidationException

```
public class EnumValidationException extends Exception {

    private String enumValue = null;
    private String enumName = null;

    public String getEnumValue() {
        return enumValue;
    }

    public void setEnumValue(String enumValue) {
        this.enumValue = enumValue;
    }

    public String getEnumName() {
        return enumName;
    }

    public void setEnumName(String enumName) {
        this.enumName = enumName;
    }

    public EnumValidationException(String enumValue, String enumName) {
        super(enumValue);

        this.enumValue = enumValue;
        this.enumName = enumName;
    }

    public EnumValidationException(String enumValue, String enumName, Throwable cause) {
        super(enumValue, cause);

        this.enumValue = enumValue;
        this.enumName = enumName;
    }
}
```

I have enum as below, with a special annotation @JsonCreator on a method create

```
public enum PaymentType {

    CREDIT("Credit"), DEBIT("Debit"); 

    private final String type;

    PaymentType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return type;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static PaymentType create (String value) throws EnumValidationException {
        if(value == null) {
            throw new EnumValidationException(value, "PaymentType");
        }
        for(PaymentType v : values()) {
            if(value.equals(v.getType())) {
                return v;
            }
        }
        throw new EnumValidationException(value, "PaymentType");
    }
}
```

Finally RestErrorHandler class,

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ValidationErrorDTO> processValidationIllegalError(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod, WebRequest webRequest) {

        EnumValidationException exception = (EnumValidationException) ex.getMostSpecificCause();

        ValidationErrorDTO errorDTO = new ValidationErrorDTO();
        errorDTO.setEnumName(exception.getEnumName());
        errorDTO.setEnumValue(exception.getEnumValue());
        errorDTO.setErrorMessage(exception.getEnumValue() + " is an invalid " + exception.getEnumName());
        return new ResponseEntity<ValidationErrorDTO>(errorDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

ValidationErrorDTO is the dto with setters/getters of enumValue, enumName and errorMessage. Now when you send POST call to controller endpoint /reviews with below request

```
{"paymentType":"Credit2"}
```

Then code returns response as 400 with below response body -

```
{
    "enumValue": "Credit2",
    "enumName": "PaymentType",
    "errorMessage": "Credit2 is an invalid PaymentType"
}
```

Let me know if it resolves your issue.

Comment: I like the idea. But IMHO, it's not scalable. If there are 100 enums, I don't want to write `@JsonCreator` for all those enums.

Answer (score 1):

Yon can achieve this using  `@ControllerAdvice` as follows

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler(value = {InvalidFormatException.class})
    public ResponseEntity handleIllegalArgumentException(InvalidFormatException exception) {

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(exception.getMessage());
    }
```

Basically , the idea is to catch `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException` and handle it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

@Valid has to do with Hibernate bean validation. Currently enum type is not supported out of the box. I found this answer to be the closet, https://funofprograming.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/java-enum-validator/, the drawback however is that you have to make the enum field of type String instead.